# How to enrich the response from original payload

Tags: mule

I want to enrich my message (POJO) properties from original payload stored in flow variable

```
    <set-variable variableName="SupplierRequest" value="#[payload]" doc:name="SupReq"/>

        <flow-ref name="GetSupplierRequestDetail" doc:name="GetReqData"/>

    <set-variable variableName="SupplierRequestData" value="#[payload]" doc:name="SupReqData"/>
```

In above code, I need couple of SupplierRequestData POJO properties to be set with properties from SupplierRequest POJO.

Do I need to write custom transformer or any other solution?

Comment: Not clear .. what you want exactly .. Could you pls update the question with more details ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should use the [enritcher](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Message+Enricher). But given that you already have the original payload in a flow variable you could just use an [expression component](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Expression+Component+Reference) as an expression transformer would imply a transformation from A to B while this is modification of A with B:

```
<expression-component><![CDATA[message.payload.propertyName = flowVars.myOrigPayload.myProp]]></expression-component>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Here enricher can't work because it would enrich request with response whereas I wanted to enrich response with request.